# CSS position:fixed causes higher z-index box-shadow to fail

Tags: html, css

I'm using a pseudo-element to create a glow effect (`box-shadow`) on a div.

The "background" div below that glowing div is `position:fixed`. When I have the lower/bg div as `position:absolute`, everything looks good.

But when it's `position:fixed` (which I need), Safari displays the box-shadow at a much lower opacity. Firefox/Chrome are fine.

Any idea of how to solve the problem with Safari?

```css
body {
  background-color: #39f;
}

#mybackground {
  z-index: -15;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  /* With position:absolute, it's good, but position:fixed makes the box-shadow below very light */
  background-image: url("image.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#mytext {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

#mytext:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -10;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 25px #060;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px 25px #060;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="mybackground"></div>
  <div id="mytext">This is a test</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please, provide your code snippets on codepen, so I can help you

Comment: what's your safari version?

Answer (score 0):

According to the safari version, it depends on.

If safari 3.1 - 4

Partial supprot with prefix `-webkit-`

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px 25px #060;
```

If safari 5

Support with prefix `-webkit-`

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px 25px #060;
```

If safari 5.1 - 14

```
box-shadow: 0 0 25px 25px #060;
```

For further explanation, follow this https://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow